Why 7/4 (175%) for zoom and speedup?
Many user interfaces allow zooming (or speeding up) by pre-configured amounts.  For example, Google Chrome suggests zooming with the +/- adjustments, and youtube lets you speed up or slow down the video, but only by set amounts.
Why is 175% (7/4) so often one of these options?
I understand the reasoning for double/half; these may also be faster to rescale.  I understand the UX desire for +/- 10%, or 1/3 or 1/4.  But why is 7/4 such a frequent option, even when it causes double/200% to scroll off the bottom of the choices, and therefore to require extra fine interaction, thus defeating much of the value of pre-sets?

This is an overlapping of two otherwise unrelated design "decisions". The default entries shown by a drop down is 5. If this is not adapted, adding more options will only be accessible by scrolling. The 175% on its own is not a problematic entry that pushes 200% "out of reach" - Using the unadjusted value of visible drop-down items is the problem. Caused by the thinking that steps of 25% is a good way to handle increments for speeds or zoom (which is debatable; 20% prolly would be more effective)
Recently it got more common to provide a slider to chose zoom levels. This way the full range of steps is equally accessible.

So it was sort of a couple of defaults?  1/4 seemed good and anything else would take effort and maybe justification; expanding the number of choices is easier than (or at least separate from) expanding the space for them?

@JimJ.Jewett Yes, exactly. At least in case of the YouTube player it is obvious that they missed to adjust the behaviour of that speedup popup menu properly. The Math behind the layout says something like "Use 90% of the player height to display the menu" - not considering how many items there are and what this means for the last entry (200%). Also the 25% increment choice is totally arbitrary. There might be optimization reasons behind it but with today's computing powers it does not affect performance when using "skewed" numbers like increments of 12% etc.
